# confused about Prolog Response

Tags: prolog

Consider:

```
bar([], Ws, Ws).
bar([X|Xs], Ys, [X|Zs]) :- bar(Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

1) How does this have no Solutions

```
bar([1,2], [], [X,X]).
```

2) How does this have only One Solution when Z=5?

```
bar([5,Y], [Y,5], [Z,Z|_]).
```

3)How does this have only One Solution when Z=5 and Y = 5?

```
bar([_,Y], [5,5], [Z,Z,Z|_]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider the meaning of `bar/3`: the rule has three arguments representing lists. `bar/3` returns a solution when the last list is a concatenation of the first two:

```
bar([1,2,3], [4,5], X)       // X=[1,2,3,4,5]
bar([1,2,3], X, [1,2,3,4,5]) // X=[4,5]
bar(X, [4,5], [1,2,3,4,5])   // X=[1,2,3]
```

Knowing this, you can figure the answers to all your questions:

- `bar([1,2], [], [X,X]).` needs X to unify with 1 and 2 at the same time, which is impossible
- `bar([5,Y], [Y,5], [Z,Z|_]).` unifies 5 with the first Z, and the second Z with Y, for a single solution
- `bar([_,Y], [5,5], [Z,Z,Z|_]).` unifies Y with the second Z, and the third Z with 5, for a single solution.

Comment: ok, I see now.  Do you have any suggestion in finding the meaning of things like bar/3 ?  I seem to have trouble visualizing that step.

Comment: @WilliamMcCarty This is somewhat tricky, and it becomes complex very quickly as the number of rules goes up. Go through each rule, and figure out what it does on high level, starting with the reduction rules, and going back to the base case. In `bar` the reduction rule checks that lists 1 and 3 have the same element at their head, and then reduces the head element. The base case checks that the reduced list 3 is the same as list 2. Combining these two steps in one leads you to an observation that the initial portion of list 3 must match list 1, and the tail portion must match list 2.

Comment: Very enlightening makes a lot more sense now, Thank you very much